# .htaccess Serve everything from the root directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a need where I need to take incoming urls and serve them from root without changing the url.

So if someone types in:
`http://example.com/randomdirectory/page.html`

it would get serve up

`http://example.com/page.html` but the url wouldn't change.

I feel like I'm close with the following, but it fails when the url ends in a trailing slash; which I would want to serve the index.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/([^.]+.html) /$2 [L]
```

Essentially, I just want to serve the same files (at root) no matter what the user types in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule instead:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.*)$ /$2 [L]
```

Comment: It works perfectly. Thank you very much. If you have time, and do not mind, could you explain what the parts of the rule are doing?

Comment: `(.+)/` matches everything up to last `/` in the URL and `(.*)` matches the last part. Then it the target we use `/$2` which is a back-reference of 2nd capturing group and `/` before `$2` makes sure it is routed to root of the website.

Comment: I looked it up. I was curious what the `(.+)` was doing. Man I was so close. Thanks again @anubhava.

Comment: sorry to bring this back up. It fails if the user inputs something like `http://example.com/something` - excluding the trailing slash.I tried making the trailing slash optional but then realized that we're matching everything up to the last `/` and using that second capture group. Would I need to creat a new rewrite rule above the current one to check for the lack of `/`?

Comment: I ended up with this:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$`
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/`

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`
`RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.*)$ /$2 [L]`